# Expire cached css on Tomcat 7 or Apache

Tags: css, apache, http, tomcat7

My employer's web app periodically makes small changes to the global styling sheet, maybe once or twice a month. We're using Tomcat 7.0.25 and Apache, each for different parts of the app.

Is there a way to configure Tomcat or Apache to tell visitors' browsers in the HTTP header to refresh the css file when it gets changed? Ideally, we'd like it to refresh only when the file changes, but it could also be fine to refresh it every time the server restarts, since most restarts coincide with an update to the app.